# Dealing with re-authentication with AccountManager in a large Android app

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I'm using AccountManager in a fairly large Android app and am using Retrofit and Otto to handle REST Requests. When a user's token no longer works a 401 error gets returned to my REST Handler.

What I would like is for the REST handler to be able to show the login activity, but since it's not an activity it can't start the getAuthToken process. My next thought is to send a message back to the calling activity using Otto to let it know that the auth token no longer works, then have that activity start the auth process, which seems like it would work, but I have several activities and it doesn't seem like the right away to go about it, handling something that is application wide on an activity level.

How do other people handle this? Do you just put the re-authentication code everywhere that a user might need to re-authenticate?